# Jmeter - Can I add thresholds to the summary report

Tags: jmeter

I'm about a week into learning JMeter and I've run a few test scripts which generate a summary.csv which contains your standard ; Samples, Average, Median etc...

[My Question]
I was wondering if there was a way to add a threshold for the summary.csv so if Average time is higher than x amount of milliseconds, then the user will be informed that the specific result was slower than expected. (Maybe this can be displayed on the summary.csv, I'm not sure what my options are tbh on how to output this)

I am aware that we can use assertions (specifically duration assertion) through the test script but the issue I have with assertions is that it stops the test once an assertion fails, stopping it from generating a summary.csv

Thank you for any input/opinions you guys have :) It is much appreciated!
Have a great day and stay safe everyone!

Comment: When you say the tests generate a summary.csv, are you referring to the HTML reports or are you manually saving it from any of the listeners?

Answer (score 0):

They are there already and they're controllable by the following [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization):

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold
```

there is also a property which can apply thresholds to specific samplers or [Transaction Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller): `jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_per_transaction`

Just declare the properties with the values of your choice in the *user.properties* file and next time you generate the dashboard its APPDEX section will reflect the thresholds.

More information: [JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard - General Settings](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general)

Comment: Hey! I just want to say thank you for your response! Took me awhile to get back because I looked into it and did a few test cases. It seems that I am indeed able to change the threshold value for specific samples but i'm unable to generate a pass/fail on samples that for example; don't satisfy the threshold, at least to my knowledge.